# Why should I not be mocking File or Path

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I've been struggling with understanding the minefield that is classes supported by the jmockit Mocking API. I found what I thought was a bug with File, but the issue was simply closed saying "Don't mock a File or Path" which no explanation. Can someone on here help me understand why certain classes should not be mocked and how I'm supposed to work around that. I'm trying to contribute to the library with bug reports, but each one I file just leaves me more confused. Pardon my ignorance, but if anyone can point me to the rationale for forbidden mocks etc. I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain that there's a fool proof list of rules.  There's always a certain degree of knowledge and taste in these matters.  Dogma is usually not a good idea.

I voted to close this question because I think a lot of it is opinion.

But with that said, I'll make an attempt.

Unit tests should be about testing individual classes, not interactions between classes.  Those are called integration tests.

If your object is calling out to other remote objects, like services, you should mock those to return the data needed for your test.  The idea is that services and their clients should also be tested individually in their own unit tests.  You need not repeat those when testing a class that depends on them.

One exception to this rule, in my opinion, are data access objects.  There is no sense in testing one of those without connecting to a remote database.  Your test needs to prove the proper operation of your code.  That requires a database connection in the case of data access objects.  These should be written to be transactional: seed the database, perform the test, and reverse the actions of the test.  The database should be in the same state when you're done.

Once your data access objects are certified as working correctly, all clients that use them should mock them.  No need to re-test.

You should not be mocking classes in the JVM.

You asked for a why about File or Stream in particular - here's one.  Take it or ignore it.

You don't have to test JVM classes because Sun/Oracle have already done that.  You know they work.  You want your class to use those classes because a failing test will expose the fact that the necessary file isn't available.  A mock won't tell me that I've neglected to put a required file in my CLASSPATH.  I want to find out during testing, not in production.

Another reason is that unit tests are also documentation.  It's a live demonstration for others to show how to properly use your class.

Comment: I still don't understand why I shouldn't be able to mock a File object. Am I supposed to only inject strings and streams, never File or Path directly? And of course I have to convince all other developers on my team of this as well.

Comment: What on earth does mocking a File even mean?  Why are you so adamant about it?  If everyone on your team tells you it's not a good idea, why are you so fixated on it?   I already gave you a meaningful example - services - that is not a String or stream.  By all means do so.  If it works for you, then great.  If not, admit that it's a waste of time and move on.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I'd be the one convincing other members on my team not to mock a File. I'm so fixated on it, because other members of my team injected a File into a class. This means that calls to getAbsolutePath need to be mocked.

Comment: A File is an external resource. You could argue it is no different from a Database. It has an interface with calls like getAbsolutePath, getRealPath, exists, etc. For a unit test that takes a File dependency, I need to be able to mock these responses, since a real file does not exist at that moment. It's the same thing as a Database.

Comment: I think I argued that I wouldn't mock a database connection when testing a data access object.  Exactly as I'm arguing that I wouldn't mock a File.  Why so insistent?  Software development is a social team sport.  People who are overly dogmatic and insisting on being right risk alienating teammates.  Besides, what is stopping you?  Do it.  See if mocking works for you.  If it does, keep doing it.  If not, let it go.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood about Database. The code IS mocking a File. There was a bug in a new version of jmockit around mocking File and I was told not to by the maintainer.  I wanted to understand why. Your question is the closest to answering that right now. But there is some serious misunderstanding of my dilemma. I'm dealing with a codebase that already uses jmockit and has many classes with mocked Files that used to work. I'm  a SEiT / Release Engineer that handles the library upgrades. I'm talking about someone else's code I was trying to get to work with a new version of jmockit.

Comment: Why is a release engineer worried about the code written by others?  Shouldn't you be asking the developers to take care of the problem?

Comment: I'd like a reason WHY, when I ask them to take care of it. The team is 2 people, maybe you can't relate.

Comment: Certainly I can relate.  I've said it before, I'll say it again - this is opinion.  Do what you wish.  If it works, great.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer, but wanted to add a final note, that I Did try it and it Did work, then all of a sudden. It Didn't work. And that is the whole dilemma. It's pretty specific to jmockit and if you don't use that framework then you may not understand. Also, I'm in a position of a junior developer trying to convince senior developers to stop injecting File and Path types. As this answer implies that is the only way to avoid this in the future. It's not an easy task. Please don't dismiss my apprehensions. I'm not in a position of authority.

Comment: I prefer Mockito.  Maybe it's time to change mocking frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

In unit test you have to test that your code is doing the right thing.  You can mock out any external pieces of code that is not the direct code being tested.  This is a strict definition of unit test and it assumes there is another form of testing called integration testing that will be done later on.  In integration testing you test how your code interacts with external elements, like a DB or another web service, or the network, or the hard drive.

If I have a piece of code that interacts with an object, like a File, and my code does 3 things to that file, then in my unit test I am going to test that my code has done those three things.

For example:

```
public void processFile(File f) {
    if (f.exists()) {
        //perform some tasks
    } else {
        //perform some other tasks
    }
}
```

To properly unit-test the code above I would run at least two unit tests.  One to test if the file exists, and the other to test that my code does the correct thing when the file does not exist.  Because unit testing, IMHO, is only testing my code and not doing integration tests, then it is perfectly fine to mock File so that you can test both branches of this method.

During integration testing you can then test with a real File as your application will be interacting with its surroundings.

Try Mockito:

I do not know why jmockit does not allow you to mock the File class.  In Mockito it can be done.  Example below.

```
import java.io.File;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class NewMain {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = mock(File.class);
        when(f.exists()).thenReturn(true);
        System.out.println("f.exists = " + f.exists());
    }

}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, yet it is no longer supported in jmockit. Or at least not considered worth fixing bugs around.