# How to properly unit test "abstracted" file handling?

Tags: java, file, unit-testing, junit, temporary-files

I have an API where file are placed in some distinct directory, and file names are made up of fixed prefix/postfix parts. I want to abstract away those parts, so that users of my helper class can focus on what needs to be done.

Example code:

```
static class FileManager {
    Path getFilePath(String arg) {
        return Paths.get("/whatever", "prefix_" + arg + "_postfix");
    }

    void deleteFileIfExists(Path path) {
        if (path.toFile().exists())
            path.toFile().delete();
    }

    public void deleteFileIfExistsUsing(String arg) {
        deleteFileIfExists(getFilePath(arg));
    }
}


@Rule
public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void testGetFilePath() {
    assertThat(new FileManager().getFilePath("bar"), is(Paths.get("/whatever/prefix_bar_postfix")));
}

@Test
public void testDelete() throws IOException {
    File subfolder = temporaryFolder.newFolder("whatever");
    File fileToDelete = new File(subfolder, "prefix_bar_postfix");
    fileToDelete.createNewFile();
    assertThat(fileToDelete.exists(), is(true));
    new FileManager().deleteFileIfExists(fileToDelete.toPath());
    assertThat(fileToDelete.exists(), is(false));
}
```

As you can see, it is possible to fully test `getFilePath()` and `deleteFileIfExists()`. But is there a meaningful way to test the one API `deleteFileIfExistsUsing(String)`?

The only option I see: have *another* class that provides the Path-based  calls, and then give the `FileManager` an instance of that class ... that could then be mocked. But that feels a bit like overkill.

So: are the other ways to test the public method from `FileManager`?

( side note: one goal is that the unit test is somehow platform independent. The above actually works on Linux and Windows for example )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject a `Function<String, Path>` into the constructor of `FileManager`:

```
static class FileManager {
    private final Function<String, Path> pathFactory;

    FileManager(Function<String, Path> pathFactory) {
        this.pathFactory = pathFactory;
    }

    Path getFilePath(String arg) {
        return pathFactory.apply("/whatever/prefix_" + arg + "_postfix");
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you can inject `Paths::get` in production code, and something that, say, returns mock `Path`s in tests.

Comment: At the point where you're using a `BiFunction`, I might lean towards defining a specific interface, `PathFactory`: it's really not clear what those two parameters are meant to mean.

Comment: Sorry, for the forth and back. Your comment makes total sense, so I rolled back to the original content.

Answer (score 0):

You should Mock `path.toFile().exists()` to get two unit tests, one mocking an existing file and one mocking a non existing file.
An example with mockito on [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351637/junit-mockito-framework)

Comment: `path` is a parameter, and in my case, the corresponding Path object is created **within** the production code. I don't see how one could mock that object. That is the whole point of my question.

Comment: So did you check that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308463/why-should-i-not-be-mocking-file-or-path)

Comment: I am aware that one should be cautious about mocking such things. But in the end, I do have production code that has to read/delete specific files, and I want to make sure that I have unit tests covering that nicely.